# ExtJS, store, HasMany - BelongsTo and update process: howto?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have two data models: `Writer.AttributValeur` and `Writer.Produit`.

`Writer.Produit` has `HasMany` / `BelongsTo` relationship with `Writer.AttributValeur`.

Thus the definition is like this:

```
Ext.define('Writer.AttributValeur', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },  
        'description',
        'val'
    ],  
    belongsTo: 'Writer.Produit'
});

Ext.define('Writer.Produit', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
            name: 'id',
            type: 'int',
            useNull: true
        },  
        'titre',
        'description'
    ],
    hasMany: {
        model: 'Writer.AttributValeur',
        name: 'attributs'
    }   
});

var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Produit',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'json/liste_view/',
            create:  'json/item/?mode=create',
            update:  'json/item/?mode=update',
            destroy: 'json/item/?mode=destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data'
        }
    }
});
```

Now, when I read the file, asking for "Produits", there's an AJAX answer that works perfectly:

[image: AJAX answer that works perfectly]

And in each "row", there are many `Writer.AttributValeur` (I've aliased them as "attributs" see picture):

[image: many Writer.AttributValeur]

The problem is when I insert a `Writer.AttributValeur` in this "`attributs`" field, like this:

```
form.getRecord().attributs().add(newrecord);
```

It works perfectly but when I call `store.sync()` nothing happens. So I mark by hand the record as `dirty`:

```
form.getRecord().attributs().add(newrecord);
form.getRecord().setDirty();
form.getRecord().store.sync();
```

Now it's sent, but the `attributs` are not sent! See:

[image: Showing that the attributs are not sent]

How shall I do to "add" this into the update process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the override stuff:

```
Ext.data.writer.Json.override({
  {*/*
     * This function overrides the default implementation of
     * json writer. Any hasMany relationships will be submitted
     * as nested objects
     */*}
    getRecordData: function(record) {
        var me = this, i, association, childStore, data = {}; 
        data = me.callParent([record]);

        /* Iterate over all the hasMany associations */
        for (i = 0; i < record.associations.length; i++) {
            association = record.associations.get(i);
            if (association.type == 'hasMany')  {
                data[association.name] = []; 
                childStore = eval('record.'+association.name+'()');

                //Iterate over all the children in the current association
                childStore.each(function(childRecord) {

                    //Recursively get the record data for children (depth first)
                    var childData = this.getRecordData.call(this, childRecord);
                    if (childRecord.dirty | childRecord.phantom | (childData != null)){
                        data[association.name].push(childData);
                        record.setDirty();
                    }   
                }, me);
            }   
        }   
        return data;
    }   
});
```

And here's an example of how I'm using it:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Writer.Produit',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            read: 'json/liste_view/',
            create:  'json/item/?mode=create',
            update:  'json/item/?mode=update',
            destroy: 'json/item/?mode=destroy'
        },
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            successProperty: 'success',
            root: 'data',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: new Ext.data.writer.Json( {
            type: 'json',
            writeAllFields: true,
            root: 'data'
        })
    }
});
```

And when I add a nested record here's how I do this with `attributs` which is oneToMany association (see my question). It's important to note that I set Dirty **all nested** records so that I'm sure they're sent:

```
var rec = this.formDst.getRecord(),
    atts = rec.attributs();
atts.add(sel);
for (var i = 0; i <atts.data.items.length; i++) {
    atts.data.items[i].setDirty();
};
rec.setDirty();
rec.store.sync();
this.close();
```

Comment: Did you very that it works? Also can you note pieces that were omitted from the solution posted on the Sencha thread?

Comment: Here is another interesting approach with forms: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9891694/834424

Comment: I've been working on it 20/7 so I've edited the solution, because my other solution didn't work when inserting new records. Now (1) everything works fine (2) it calls the parent's function (= sencha's original `getRecordData()` function), which is safer, smarter and will probably stay compatible in the long run (3) it's much shorter thus easier to understand

Comment: why is this.writeAllFields false when i save?

Comment: @BobTodd it is because this solution didn't handle scope correctly (I fixed it now)... inside the parent getRecordData, `this` is the browser window!  Updated solution by changing `data = ExtDataWriterJsonOriginal_getRecordData(record);` to `data = me.callParent([record]);` and getting rid of ugly var.  This solved the problem for me.

Comment: May I suggest that you change `eval('record.'+association.name+'()');` to `record[association.name]();`

Comment: I got this working with Sencha 2.3 by changing `association.type` to `association.getType()` and `association.name` to `association.getName()`.

Comment: nice solution, just another suggestion, use Ext.define for the override, like this:     `Ext.define("Ext.ux.data.writer.Json", {
        override: "Ext.data.writer.Json",
        getRecordData: function (record, operation) { .... } }); `

Answer (score 2):

i liked the simple solution so i also added belongsTo Support:

```
Ext.data.writer.Json.override({
getRecordData:function (record) {

    var me = this, i, association, childStore, data = {};
    data = me.callParent([record]);

    /* Iterate over all the hasMany associations */
    for (i = 0; i < record.associations.length; i++) {

        association = record.associations.get(i);
        if (association.type == 'hasMany') {
            data[association.name] = [];
            childStore = eval('record.' + association.name + '()');

            //Iterate over all the children in the current association
            childStore.each(function (childRecord) {

                //Recursively get the record data for children (depth first)
                var childData = this.getRecordData.call(this, childRecord);
                if (childRecord.dirty | childRecord.phantom | (childData != null)) {
                    data[association.name].push(childData);
                    record.setDirty();
                }
            }, me);
        }

        if(association.type == 'belongsTo') {

            // we need ucfirst
            var method = 'get' + association.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + association.name.slice(1);
            var childRecord = eval('record.' + method + '()');
            var childData = this.getRecordData.call(this, childRecord);

            if (childRecord.dirty | childRecord.phantom | (childData != null)) {
                data[association.name] = childData;
                record.setDirty();
            }

        }

    }
    return data;
}
```

});

Comment: Thanks, was about to add this in myself.

Answer (score 0):

From the sencha docs - looks like you need to call sync on `form.getRecord().attributs()` and not on the main record. Can you try that?

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.HasManyAssociation

Comment: I've already tried that: nothing happens. Tried to put `setDirty()` everywhere but exceptions all the time (= bad place) except with `this.formDst.getRecord().setDirty();`.

Comment: I've found a very interesting question with nice answers here http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store. It happens that there's nothing done to save "automatically" nested associations, which is not logical: it's possible to load "automatically" nested associations, but not to save them "automatically"... Doesn't work with ExtJs4.0: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getData'`. Damn it x 2! Doesn't work with ExtJS 4.1: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'persist' of undefined`.

Comment: (I was trying to add the latest solution with **`Ext.data.writer.DeepJson`** class. Doesn't work. I'll try with other sample, maybe that will work, only God knows...

Comment: Well.. if it's a bug (omission) from standard ExtJs logic - I would suggest expanding standard writer by including this additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not supported in 4.0x and is not yet on the feature path for 4.1 as far as I know. 
There have been some attempts at resolution however, see this thread: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?141957-Saving-objects-that-are-linked-hasMany-relation-with-a-single-Store

Also another interesting approach with forms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9891694/834424 by Jamie Sutherland

Comment: Exactly. That's why I'm posting a solution that works to help the community. Anyway, if nested "modified" records aren't posted with the main record, it break the whole KISS + DRY principles.

Comment: I agree, I've always felt that the model associations in 4.0 were half baked at best.