# ExtJs and nested models

Tags: extjs, extjs4

Let's say I have a model called Vehicle

```
Ext.define('AM.model.Vehicle', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'brandId',  type: 'int'}, 
        {name: 'brandName',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'modelId',  type: 'int'}, 
        {name: 'modelName',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'yearOfRelease',  type: 'int'}
    ]

});
```

As you can see, the vehicle model has fields "brandId", "brandName", etc.
For example, I want to edit an instance of this model.
I create an edit form, which has combobox linked to 'brandId' field.
Then I save the form values to a model instance with this

```
values = form.getValues();
record.set(values);
```

It all works fine, but there is a problem with all the fields that represent some outer models:
only id's are updated, while all other fields, that depend on id remain the same.

In a regular OOP language(Java for example), I would create a class CarBrand 
and put an instance of this class inside the Vehicle class.
In ExtJs 4 they have hasMany relationship, but don't have hasOne.

What is the best approach in ExtJS 4 for such nested models?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

4.0.* doesn't support the hasOne relationship. 4.1 is meant to support it.

for 4.0.7 I have the following override in place.

```
Ext.define('HOD.overrides.Form', {}, function() {

/*
 * Implementing a nested setValues for forms with
 * arrays in them.
 */
Ext.override(Ext.form.Basic, {
    setValues: function(values, arrayField) {
        var me = this;

        function setVal(fieldId, val) {
            if (arrayField) {
                fieldId = arrayField + '.' + fieldId;
            }
            var field = me.findField(fieldId);
            if (field) {
                field.setValue(val);
                if (me.trackResetOnLoad) {
                    field.resetOriginalValue();
                }
            } else if(Ext.isObject(val)) {
                me.setValues(val, fieldId);
            }
        }

        if (Ext.isArray(values)) {
            // array of objects
            Ext.each(values, function(val) {
                setVal(val.id, val.value);
            });
        } else {
            // object hash
            Ext.iterate(values, setVal);
        }
        return this;
    },
    /**
     * Persists the values in this form into the passed {@link Ext.data.Model} object in a beginEdit/endEdit block.
     * @param {Ext.data.Model} record The record to edit
     * @return {Ext.form.Basic} this
     */
    updateRecord: function(record) {
        var values = this.getFieldValues(),
        name,
        obj = {};

        function populateObj(record, values) {
            var obj = {},
            name;

            record.fields.each(function(field) {
                name = field.name;
                if (field.model) {
                    var nestedValues = {};
                    var hasValues = false;
                    for(var v in values) {
                        if (v.indexOf('.') > 0) {
                            var parent = v.substr(0, v.indexOf('.'));
                            if (parent == field.name) {
                                var key = v.substr(v.indexOf('.') + 1);
                                nestedValues[key] = values[v];
                                hasValues = true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (hasValues) {
                        obj[name] = populateObj(Ext.create(field.model), nestedValues);
                    }
                } else if (name in values) {
                    obj[name] = values[name];
                }
            });
            return obj;
        }

        obj = populateObj(record, values);

        record.beginEdit();
        record.set(obj);
        record.endEdit();

        return this;
    }
});
```

Whats this lets me do is in my forms I create them with names like so.

```
// Contact details
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    layout: 'anchor',
    fieldDefaults: {
        anchor: '80%',
        allowBlank: true
    },
    items: [

    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'homePhone',
        fieldLabel: 'Home phone number'
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'mobilePhone',
        fieldLabel: 'Mobile phone number'
    }]
},
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    layout: 'anchor',
    fieldDefaults: {
        anchor: '80%',
        allowBlank: true
    },
    items: [
    {
        name: 'address.id',
        xtype: 'hidden'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.building',
        fieldLabel: 'Building'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.street',
        fieldLabel: 'Street'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.city',
        fieldLabel: 'City'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.county',
        fieldLabel: 'County'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.postcode',
        fieldLabel: 'Postcode'
    },
    {
        name: 'address.country',
        fieldLabel: 'Country'
    }
    ]
},
]
```

Notice the . in the name field which lets the overridden setValues and updateRecord form know it needs to map these values to the new model, which is defined in the model like so.

```
Ext.define('HOD.model.Employee', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        // Person Class
        // Auto
        'id',
        'name',
        'homePhone',
        'mobilePhone',
        {model: 'HOD.model.Address', name: 'address'}, //Address
        {model: 'HOD.model.Contact', name: 'iceInformation'} //Person
    ]
});

Ext.define('HOD.model.Address', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        'building',
        'street',
        'city',
        'county',
        'postcode',
        'country'
    ],
    belongsTo: 'Employee'
});
```

Comment: This is an interestiing solution. Also there is a similar thread about one 2 many associations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871440/extjs-store-one2many-and-update-process-howto

Answer (score 2):

There is no nested models, however it's not clear from your example why are you doing this. Why do you need to save both id and names in the Vehicle record if you already have that relationship in some other database (I assume you have something like Brand Dictionary where you keep all pairs id/name?).

Update: I would do the following:

- Keep only brand_id in the vehicle record.
- When you have a form, present combobox with values from the dictionary store and update brand_id
- When you have a grid - define custom 'renderer' function for the column and get brand name from the dictionary store by brand_id

Here is sample code for such column:

```
{ text: 'Brand Name', dataIndex: 'brand_id', 
    renderer: function(value) {
       var rec = Ext.getStore('BrandDict').getById(value);
       return rec ? rec.get('name') : '';
}
```

Comment: You are right, I have Brands Dictionary. I need to update the names to display the correct value in the grid. What I don't like in this approach - I have to copy all the fields from Brand model to Vehicle model. In my example there is only one additional field - name, but there can be much more...

Comment: No you dont. If you just need to display them in the grid - use custom renderer but still have them edit same combobox field.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point with renderer. Can you explain?

Comment: Thanks, it's a good solution! Are there any perfomance issues in this approach? Let's say, I have a grid with 1000 rows and each row has references to 10 different dictionaries. This means I will have 10000 calls to stores. That frightens me.

Comment: Check and see. I don't think it will be 10000 calls right of the bat. But then again - there are probably some ways of optimizing it.