# ExtJS 6 Saving One-To-Many Relationships

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have been using [this ExtJS 4 override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9871440/extjs-store-hasmany-belongsto-and-update-process-howto) to save a record along with its associated data and it has worked great.  I am now in the process of upgrading to ExtJS 6 and it appears it will no longer work.

The problem seems to be with the line `for (var i = 0; i < record.associations.length; i++)`. It looks like the record object no longer has an associations property.

Considering this has been a somewhat serious limitation with ExtJS I thought they might have addressed it in the new versions but I am unable to find anything.

Does anyone know of a way to get this to work in ExtJS 6 either using an override or by some other means?

Comment: what is the Type of "record" variable?

Comment: It is an instance of an Ext.data.Model

Comment: did you try using getAssociatedData method?